# Jsoup after method doesn't work the way it's expected

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a method which has a property description of type "Element" and then I try to add another element using Jsoup.after method.

However, it produces

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null`.

On the other hand, the append method works so well, but I that's not what I really want.

The code is below:

```
private static void buildTotalvaluesTable2()
{
    Element readyDesc = new Element("p style=\"margin-top:5px\">This is description</p");

    Element totalValuesTable = new Element("table style=\"width:100%; border: 0px; margin-top:20px;\" class=\"hidden\">" +
            "<tbody></tbody>" +
            "</table");

    readyDesc.after(totalValuesTable.outerHtml());

    System.out.println(readyDesc.outerHtml());
}
```

What I really want to achieve is simply totalValuesTable going after readyDesc.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with explaining what does it mean to set element `b` as sibling of element `a` (here represented by `a.after(b)`).
In short it means placing element `b` **in `parent` element of element `a`** at position next to (after) `a` element.

So at this point we can see that **main problem** with your code is that it doesn't provide any link to *parent* element *in which sibling should be placed*.

Simple solution would be to

1. create `Element` or `Document` representing parent,
2. assign `a` element as a child of parent element
3. (only after 1. 2.) assign `b` element as sibling of `a`,

In other words something like:

```
Element parent = new Element("body");

Element a = ...
parent.appendChild(first); // create parent-child relation

Element b = ...
a.after(b);      // now `a` knows about its parent element so it knows 
                 // to which element append `b`
```

**Second problem** is that you are not using `new Element(...)` correctly at

```
new Element("p style=\"margin-top:5px\">This is description</p");
```

Purpose of that constructor isn't to *create and setup* but only *create* HTML element. Customizing that element should be done later.

In other words don't use `new Element("<tag with='attributes'>and other elements</tag>")` but `new Element("tagName")` and set up that element via dedicated methods like:

```
Element readyDesc = new Element("p");//use only name of tag, without < and >
System.out.println(readyDesc); //raw form: <p></p>

//customize tag
readyDesc.attr("style", "margin-top:5px");
readyDesc.text("This is description");
System.out.println(readyDesc);//customized: <p style="margin-top:5px">This is description</p>
```